# How to add custom font in shopify site

Tags: html, css, fonts, shopify

**I have added font code**

```
    @font-face {   font-family: 'Gotham-Book';   src:url('{{ "Gotham-Book.eot" | asset_url }}');   src:url('{{ "Gotham-Book.eot"
    | asset_url }}#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('{{ "Gotham-Book.woff" | asset_url }}') format('woff'),
    url('{{ "Gotham-Book.ttf" | asset_url }}') format('truetype'),
    url('{{ "Gotham-Book.svg | asset_url }}#Gotham-Book') format('svg');      font-weight: normal;   font-style: normal; }
```

Also uploaded the font files in  Assets Folder.

> Question: How to use font for all headings, My theme using sass
>       variables,

Comment: https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/store/use-font-face-fonts

Comment: @Leon,  Please read my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Upload font files in assets folder
>
> If your font has multiple files, you will have to repeat this process for each one.

[image]

> Link The Fonts In Your CSS
>
> Open your theme’s CSS file. In most themes, this is called theme.scss.liquid

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'your-font';
    src: url('./your-font.eot');
    src: url('./your-font.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('./your-font.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('./your-font.woff') format('woff'),
         url('./your-font.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

> Replace font-family in your theme.scss.liquid

Comment: Thanks, @Varsha Dhadge my problem resolved already but your answer very helpful to others

Comment: @MIkeJ. How did u resolve your issue? Can you share please?